# ASP.NET Custom Controls - Composites

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, user-controls, controls

### Summary

Hi All,
OK, further into my adventures with custom controls...

In summary, here is that I have learned of three main "classes" of custom controls. Please feel free to correct me if any of this is wrong!

1. **UserControls** - Which inherit from *UserControl* and are contained within an *ASCX* file. These are pretty limited in what they can do, but are a quick and light way to get some UI commonality with designer support.
2. **Custom Composite Controls** - These are controls that inherit from *WebControl* where you add pre-existing controls to the control within the *CreateChildControls* method. This provides great flexibility, but lack of designer support without additional coding. They are highly portable though since they can be compiled into a DLL.
3. **Custom Rendered Controls** - Similar to Custom Composite Controls, these are added to a Web Control Library project. The rendering of the control is completely controlled by the programmer by overriding the *Render* method.

### My Thoughts..

OK, so while playing with custom composites, I found the following:

- You have little/no control over the HTML output making it difficult to "debug".
- The *CreateChildControls* (and subsequent methods) can get real busy with *Controls.Add(myControl)* everywhere.
- I found rendering tables (be it for layout or content) to be considerably awkward.

### The Question(s)..

So, I admit, I am new to this so I could be way off-base with some of my points noted above..

- Do you use Composites?
- Do you have any neat tricks to control the HTML output?
- Do you just say "to hell with it" and go ahead and create a custom rendered control?

**Its something I am keen to get really firm in my mind since I know how much *good* control development can cut overall development time.**

I look forward to your answers ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I say go ahead with the custom rendered control. I find that in most cases the composite can be easier done and used in a UserControl, but anything beyond that and you'd need to have a finer degree of control (pun unintended) to merit your own rendering strategy.

There maybe controls that are simple enough to merit a composite (e.g., a textbox combined with a javascript/dhtml based datepicker, for example) but beyond that one example, it looks like custom rendered controls are the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another extension method that I use for custom rendering:

```
 public static void WriteControls
        (this HtmlTextWriter o, string format, params object[] args)
 { 
    const string delimiter = "<2E01A260-BD39-47d0-8C5E-0DF814FDF9DC>";
    var controls  = new Dictionary<string,Control>();

    for(int i =0; i < args.Length; ++i)
    { 
       var c = args[i] as Control; 
       if (c==null) continue;
       var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
       controls[guid] = c;
       args[i] = delimiter+guid+delimiter;
    }

    var _strings = string.Format(format, args)
                         .Split(new string[]{delimiter},
                                StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach(var s in _strings)
    { 
       if (controls.ContainsKey(s)) 
           controls[s].RenderControl(o);
       else 
           o.Write(s);
    }
}
```

Then, to render a custom composite in the RenderContents() method I write this:

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter o)
{ 
    o.WriteControls
         (@"<table>
               <tr>
                    <td>{0}</td>
                    <td>{1}</td>
               </tr>
             </table>"
            ,Text
            ,control1);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Rob, you are right. The approach I mentioned is kind of a hybrid. The advantage of having ascx files around is that on every project I've seen, designers would feel most comfortable with editing actual markup and with the ascx you and a designer can work separately. If you don't plan on actual CSS/markup/design changes on the controls themselves later, you can go with a custom rendered control. As I said, my approach is only relevant for more complicated scenarios (and these are probably where you need a designer :))

Answer (score 1):

I often use composite controls. Instead of overriding Render or RenderContents, just assign each Control a CssClass and use stylesheets. For multiple Controls.Add, I use an extension method:

```
//Controls.Add(c1, c2, c3)
static void Add(this ControlCollection coll, params Control[] controls)
 { foreach(Control control in controls) coll.Add(control);
 }
```

For quick and dirty rendering, I use something like this:

```
writer.Render(@"<table>
                   <tr><td>{0}</td></tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>", Text);
control1.RenderControl(writer);
writer.Render("</td></tr></table>");
```

For initializing control properties, I use property initializer syntax:

```
childControl = new Control {  ID="Foo"
                            , CssClass="class1"
                            , CausesValidation=true;
                           };
```

Answer (score 1):

Using custom composite controls has a point in a situation where you have a large web application and want to reuse large chunks in many places. Then you would only add child controls of the ones you are developing instead of repeating yourself.
On a large project I've worked recently what we did is the following:

- Every composite control has a container. Used as a wrapped for everything inside the control.
- Every composite control has a template. An ascx file (without the <%Control%> directive) which only contains the markup for the template.
- The container (being a control in itself) is initialized from the template.
- The container exposes properties for all other controls in the template.
- You only use this.Controls.Add([the_container]) in your composite control.

In fact you need a base class that would take care of initializing a container with the specified template and also throw exceptions when a control is not found in the template. Of course this is likely to be an overkill in a small application. If you don't have reused code and markup and only want to write simple controls, you're better off using User Controls.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to make use of this technique to make design-time easier:

http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2007/10/19/Render-User-Control-as-String-Template.aspx

Basically you create an instance of a user control at runtime using the LoadControl method, then hand it a statebag of some kind, then attach it to the control tree. So your composite control would actually function like more of a controller, and the .ascx file would be like a view.

This would save you the trouble of having to instantiate the entire control tree and style the control in C#!