# what are the difference between asp.net server control and html server control

Tags: asp.net

hi all
what are the difference between asp.net server control and html server control? when do can i use these controls and which is better to app.

thanks
saj

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084/asp-net-aspxxx-controls-versus-standard-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ASP.Net server control has a rich set of (server side) methods and/or properties and might not map to a single html element.

An html server control is just the server side representation of one html element.

Which is "better"? That entirely depends on your needs.