# what is composite control in asp.net?How we create composite control?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, composite-controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET Custom Controls - Composites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532/asp-net-custom-controls-composites)

How to make and use composite control in asp.net?

Comment: I think you should instead ask "How to google for the simplest questions?"

Answer (score 2):

A composite control is a control that's *composed* of some child controls (which are added by overriding `CreateChildControls` method). For a detailed article on them see [MSDN: A Crash Course on ASP.NET Control Development: Building Composite Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479016.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

here are some tutorials:

[codesource.com](http://www.codersource.net/published/view/288/creating_composite_control_in_asp_net.aspx)

[Codeguru.com](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/webforms/article.php/c12725)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479016.aspx)

A google for "Creating a composite Control would have helped you"

Answer (score 0):

> "A composite control is one made up of
>   other built-in controls, such as text
>   boxes. You also can create a control
>   from scratch if you don't want to use
>   the built-in controls"

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/webforms/article.php/c12725